# start mysql with --skip-slave-start

Tags: mysql, database-replication

I need to start mysql server with '--skip-slave-start' option, as stated in tutorials/docs.

How can I achive that?

trying the next commands does not work:

```
service mysql start --skip-slave-start
```

start: invalid option: --skip-slave-start

```
mysql>SLAVE START --skip-slave-start;
```

ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're getting a syntax error with this:

```
mysql>SLAVE START --skip-slave-start;
```

because that's not a valid statement.

This here

```
service mysql start --skip-slave-start
```

invokes another script calling mysqld. Either you adjust the script, or easiest would be you put the option in your config file (most probably under `/etc/my.conf`

like this

```
[mysqld]
skip-slave-start
```

Comment: It is a command line attribute as well, but you need to pass it directly to the `mysqld` process or to the `mysqld_safe` wrapper script. Typically though you should be good with the config file.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-slave-start
```